# Rails version clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-14.04, circular-reference

I'm currently working out of the book Agile Web Development with Rails (Fourth edition) and it instructs users to use rails version 3.2.0.

I am getting an error when running "rake test" (see below)
http://pastebin.com/RZeWvFYf

After doing some looking around, it ***appears*** that this is a bug caused by my rails version.

I would like to fix this massive error dump, but it seems my only answer is to change rails version. I'd like to know if its safe to do so, or if there is a fix I didn't know about.

Thanks!

Edit- full rake about results

http://pastebin.com/yBSnjUt7
(refuses to work in code tags)

Comment: can you tell your Ruby version ?  I don't think this issue belongs to Rails version. There can be problem with particular version of Rack.

Comment: Of course @HassanAkram , My ruby version is  2.2.3 (x86_64-linux),